# Using bake on shared hosting Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to get bake working on my subdomain which is under shared hosting.

Is there a way we can get this working? I know how to connect to server via ssh shell but then what do I do after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `cd` to the directory where the cake script is. On a Linux webserver, this would probably be something like `~/cake/console/`, if you've put the CakePHP libs outside your web-accessible directories. If you've put everything into your web directory you'll probably have to go somewhere like `~/www/cake/console/`.

Then simply type `./cake bake` and take it from there.

You shouldn't have to do anything with environment variables. This is only necessary if you want to be able to run the cake console from any directory. I find it less of a hassle to just `cd` into the cake console's directory and run it using `./cake`.

Answer (score 0):

same as local machine `cd <path_to_console>` `cake` 
if you do not know `path_to_console` ask for host support, 
also `path_to_console` may be in environment path then just use `cake` in all dirs

Comment: depends of OS, for mac/linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263218/cakephp-set-cake-environment-variable for windows use google

Comment: I mean on UNIX shared hosting server where you wouldn't have access to setting environment variables

Comment: I can do it on my computer no problems it's the problem with the server

Comment: ask support of shared hosting